# rayHandler.render() causes black screen in box2DLightsVersion

Tags: java, libgdx

If I comment `rayHandler.render()` out, I see this screen ..

[image: screenshot]

However when I uncomment it, the screen goes black. Any ideas?

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private ColorCatch game;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private World world;
    private RayHandler rayHandler;
    private Body body;

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    public GameScreen (final ColorCatch gam) {

        this.game = gam;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, -98.0f), true);
        rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
        new PointLight(rayHandler, 1000, new Color(1,1,1,1), 5.0f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

        CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
        shape.setRadius(3.0f);
        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.shape = shape;
        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        bd.position.set(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2));
        bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

        body = world.createBody(bd);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        world.step(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 8, 1);

        Vector2 pos = body.getPosition();

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.identity();
        shapeRenderer.translate(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
        shapeRenderer.circle(0.0f, 0.0f, 66.0f);
        shapeRenderer.end();

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        shapeRenderer.identity();
        shapeRenderer.rect(5, 5, 10, 10);
        shapeRenderer.circle(25, 25, 10);
        shapeRenderer.end();

        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera);
        rayHandler.update();
        //rayHandler.render(); //FIXME this line causes blank screen
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        game.getBatch().dispose();
        bg.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saying you are getting a black screen but in your comment it says blank ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the radius of my `PointLight` was too small, so not visable.

Heres what worked ..

```
new PointLight(rayHandler, 1000, new Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 50.0f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
```

Comment: Good!, another possible problem that I see (and offtopic) is that your camera dimensions are too big, remember that box2d is managed in meters, not pixel. This usually will be reflected when you try to move your objects, they will be moving too slow. But, if you are conscious of this behavior, then ignore this comment haha.